# Conjugate transpose in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transpose

In the legacy Matlab code that I need to translate to C I found the following string:

```
x=fminsearch(@pmveqf,[30 30]',[],pm);
```

Can somebody please explain the meaning of
[30 30]'

in Matlab?

I know what a conjugate transpose is, but as it is applied to an empty matrix here, and this empty matrix is symmetrical, I cannot make sense of it.

What I am missing or where I am wrong?

Comment: @wakjah: Thanks! My first encounter with Matlab makes me feel absolutely silly. Please make this comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an empty matrix, it's a [1x2] matrix which, when transposed, will be a [2x1] matrix.

There is no distinction between normal and conjugate transpose here because all the values are real.

Answer (score 0):

[30 30]' is just the column matrix

```
[30;
 30]
```